# Trying to paste to two different workbooks in last row of each, but 2nd uses the 1st rows.count function. How to reset the variable or process?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

The first half of my code works fine, but the evaluation for emptyrow2 maintains the row count of the first workbook. Obviously, they are not the same number.

I can't do another sub inside the sub (or can I? is there another format that would work to do an independent subset?), but I can't seem to find a way to reset the row count itself.

How can I reset the process for the second workbook?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim AirSN As String, OilSN As String, DashNo As Single, Torque As String, PlateDeg As String, ShimDeg As String, ClampDeg As String
Dim OilArrow As String, AirArrow As String, Coning As String, Wavi As String, Comment As String, PlotDate As Date

Dim emptyrow1 As Long, emptyrow2 As Long, Summary As Variant, Master As Variant

AirSN = Range("F11")
OilSN = Range("F7")
Torque = Range("F2")
DashNo = Range("B2")
PlateDeg = Range("F3")
ShimDeg = Range("F4")
ClampDeg = Range("F5")
OilArrow = Range("F8")
AirArrow = Range("F12")
Comment = Range("F22")
PlotDate = Range("B9")

Coning = Worksheets("Coning").Range("B12")
Wavi = Worksheets("Coning").Range("B14")

Summary = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select Summary File to Open")

If Summary = False Then
    MsgBox "Nothing Chosen"
Else
    MsgBox "You chose " & Summary
End If

Workbooks.Open Summary

'Find next empty row in Summary Sheet
emptyrow1 = Worksheets("ALL").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'Annotate Summary with new iteration
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 1).Value = DashNo
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 2).Value = AirSN
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 3).Value = OilSN
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 4).Value = AirArrow
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 5).Value = OilArrow
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 6).Value = PlateDeg
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 7).Value = ClampDeg
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 8).Value = ShimDeg
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 9).Value = Torque
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 10).Value = Coning
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 11).Value = Wavi
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 12).Value = Comment
Worksheets("ALL").Cells(emptyrow1, 13).Value = PlotDate

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Workbooks.Open "U:\trib\_R&D Development Lab\_R&D Test Hardware\Coning-Waviness MASTER.xlsx"

'Find next empty row in Master Summary Sheet
emptyrow2 = Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'Annotate Summary with new iteration
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 1).Value = DashNo
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 2).Value = AirSN
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 3).Value = OilSN
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 4).Value = AirArrow
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 5).Value = OilArrow
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 6).Value = PlateDeg
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 7).Value = ClampDeg
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 8).Value = ShimDeg
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 9).Value = Torque
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 10).Value = Coning
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 11).Value = Wavi
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 12).Value = Comment
Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(emptyrow2, 13).Value = PlotDate

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End

MsgBox "Summary Updates Successful"

End Sub
```

Comment: You should define the different workbooks and worksheets you are using. Depending on `activeWorkbook` and `activeWorksheet` is risky especially when you open and close frequently. Also you can drop the `.value`

Comment: You'll want to declare workbook variables too. I.e. `Dim wbMain as Workbook, wbCopy as Workbook // Set wbMain = Workbooks("Main WB.xlsx") // Set wbCopy = Workbooks("Copy WB.xlsx")`  then set the sheets' variables to include the workbook, i.e. `wbMain.Worksheets("ALL")...`

Comment: Thanks, I had been meaning to clean things up, I was just mucking around with the structure a bit.

Answer (score 0):

there are no apparent flaws in your code

but as you have already read in comments, you have to avoid relying on *Active* objects (`workbook`, `worksheet`) while explicitly reference them

so your code could be rewritten as follows

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Summary = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select Summary File to Open")

    If Summary = False Then
        MsgBox "Nothing Chosen"
    Else
        MsgBox "You chose " & Summary
    End If


    Dim AirSN As String, OilSN As String, DashNo As Single, Torque As String, PlateDeg As String, ShimDeg As String, ClampDeg As String
    Dim OilArrow As String, AirArrow As String, Coning As String, Wavi As String, Comment As String, PlotDate As Date

    Dim emptyrow1 As Long, emptyrow2 As Long, Summary As Variant, Master As Variant


    With Worksheets("Coning")
        AirSN = .Range("F11")
        OilSN = .Range("F7")
        Torque = .Range("F2")
        DashNo = .Range("B2")
        PlateDeg = .Range("F3")
        ShimDeg = .Range("F4")
        ClampDeg = .Range("F5")
        OilArrow = .Range("F8")
        AirArrow = .Range("F12")
        Comment = .Range("F22")
        PlotDate = .Range("B9")

        Coning = .Range("B12")
        Wavi = .Range("B14")
    End With

    With Workbooks.Open(Summary)
        With .Worksheets("ALL")

            'Find next empty row in Summary Sheet
            emptyrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

            'Annotate Summary with new iteration
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 1).Value = DashNo
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 2).Value = AirSN
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 3).Value = OilSN
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 4).Value = AirArrow
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 5).Value = OilArrow
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 6).Value = PlateDeg
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 7).Value = ClampDeg
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 8).Value = ShimDeg
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 9).Value = Torque
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 10).Value = Coning
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 11).Value = Wavi
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 12).Value = Comment
            .Cells(emptyrow1, 13).Value = PlotDate
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With

    With Workbooks.Open("U:\trib\_R&D Development Lab\_R&D Test Hardware\Coning-Waviness MASTER.xlsx")
        With .Worksheets("MASTER")
            'Find next empty row in Master Summary Sheet
            emptyrow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

            'Annotate Summary with new iteration
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 1).Value = DashNo
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 2).Value = AirSN
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 3).Value = OilSN
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 4).Value = AirArrow
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 5).Value = OilArrow
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 6).Value = PlateDeg
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 7).Value = ClampDeg
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 8).Value = ShimDeg
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 9).Value = Torque
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 10).Value = Coning
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 11).Value = Wavi
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 12).Value = Comment
            .Cells(emptyrow2, 13).Value = PlotDate
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=True

    End With

    MsgBox "Summary Updates Successful"

End Sub
```

please note that most of the stataments I enclosed in `With Worksheets("Coning")` is a guess of mine: check and if necessary change the actual referenced sheet for those ranges

Comment: Thanks, that definitely cleans things up, but the issue persists. :/

Comment: give more details about the current issue

Comment: The current issue is the same as the original issue. 
In the second workbook, the emptyrow2 generates the same number as emptyrow1, which is not the same for both.

Comment: if you're using my code and get  the same value for `emptyrow1` and `emptyrow2` then  it means that both "ALL" worksheet in the workbook chosen by the user and "MASTER" worksheet in "U:\trib\_R&D Development Lab\_R&D Test Hardware\Coning-Waviness MASTER.xlsx" workbook, share the same "last" row index

Comment: I was wondering if that might be the issue. Fixed it! I found something in a forum with the comment "I don't know how or why this works, but it does" and it was the most succinct solution I've found (despite the use of active):

      Dim x As Long
      Dim y As Long
      x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
      y = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count